# Disable vuepress homepage and redirect to guide

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuepress

I've just started looking at vuepress to use as a documentation generator to one of my open-source tools (https://github.com/redskap/swagger-brake) and the tools seems to be the right fit for the job.

However, I'm kind of struggling with setting up the proper configuration. I've followed the official docs, and the base project is alright. The only thing I want to change is to get rid of the "homepage" when loading the root URL and have users being redirected to the "guide".

Hope you have some ideas.
Thanks!

Comment: do you want a url to link to the deployed GH pages?
or do you have vuepress already deployed to a url?

Comment: @DenisTsoi GH pages.

Comment: So basically, you want someone who navigates to the GitHub repo... to be redirected to the vuepress docs GH pages site?

Comment: @DenisTsoi partially. I will put a link to the GitHub repo, when they click on it they're gonna be redirected to the GH page. However, the root GH page <user>.github.io/<repo> will show the "home" screen of vuepress. What I want is to get rid of that homepage (https://redskap.github.io/swagger-brake/)

Comment: i'll submit a PR in an hour after dinner...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reviewing the github link it needs to be updated with the following.

`index.md` should have the intended homepage you'd like to select from the sidebar.

e.g.

```
# Introduction
...

// remove frontmatter.yaml
```

In your config.js

```
    nav: [
      {
        text: 'Introduction',
        link: '/',
      }
    ],
    sidebar: [
      '/',
   ]       // otherLinks
```

**Examples**

- [discord.js vuepress](https://discordjs.guide/) / [github source](https://github.com/discordjs/guide/blob/master/guide/)
- [getleon.ai vuepress](https://docs.getleon.ai/) / [github source](https://github.com/leon-ai/docs.getleon.ai/blob/master/docs/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the plugin [vuepress-plugin-redirect](https://vuepress-theme-hope.github.io/v2/redirect/) to redirect page.

e.g.

```js
import { redirectPlugin } from 'vuepress-plugin-redirect';

export default defineUserConfig({
  plugins: [
    redirectPlugin({
      config: {
        '/index.html': '/guide/',
      },
    }),
  ],
})
```